# Read structure from file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I'm trying to read a structure of a text file in a certain way. The text file is kind of a user-friendly configuration file.

Current structure of file (structure can be changed if necessary):

```
info1=exampleinfo
info2=exampleinfo2
info3="example","example2","example3"
info4="example","example2","example3"
```

There is no real difficulty in getting the first two lines, but the latter two are more difficult. I need to put both in two seperate string arrays that I can use. I could use a split string, but the problem is in that in the info4 array, the values can contain comma's (this is all user input).

How to go about solving this?

Comment: Would be much easier to choose a well-defined format that can be readily parsed. For example JSON or YAML.

Comment: As I said - structure can be changed if necessary. If you could plop an answer down using either of these methods - I'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: Want to know the easiest way to make sure a user generates a file you depend on properly?  Give them a program that will generate it for them.  That way you control the production and the consumption.  Then, if you do want to do something like JSON or just XML that's easy to parse, you can take care of any picky things like quotes, brackets, escape sequences, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having trouble writing parser is that you're not starting with a good definition of the file format.  Instead of asking how you should parse it if there are commas, you should be deciding how to properly encode values with commas.  Then parsing is simple.

If this file is written by non-technical users who can't be trusted with a complex format (like json), consider a format like:

```
info1=exampleinfo
info2=exampleinfo2
info3=example
    example2
    example3
info4=example
    example2
    example3
```

That is, don't mess around with quotes and commas. Users understand line breaks and spaces pretty well.

Comment: Thanks - I decided to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% in favor of @DavidHeffernan's solutions, JSON would be great. And @ScottMermelstein's solution of a program that builds the output - that's probably your best bet if possible, not allowing the user to make a mistake even if they wanted to.

However, if you need them to build the textfile, and you're working with users who can't be trusted to put together valid JSON, since it is a picky format, maybe try a delimiter that won't be used by the user, to separate values.

For example, pipes are always good, since practically nobody uses them:

```
info1=exampleinfo
info2=exampleinfo2
info3=example|example2|example3
info4=example|exam,ple2|example3
```

All you'd need is a rule that says their data cannot contain pipes. More than likely, the users would be ok with that.

Comment: Yeah my problem is that I cannot find a good delimiter that will not be used by the user. Pipes are one of them that tend to be actually used by the users.

Comment: @gdscei how about `╪` symbol. I don't think people use it often.

Comment: It would have to be a keyboard-friendly key to be worthwhile - so if pipes are no good, tildes (`~`) or carets (`^`) are the other ones I've seen, but if you can't find a good delimiter, you're probably best not to try this method. You could start using escape characters like JSON does, or encoding like HTML does, but once you start down that route, you're asking for problems, and would be better off forcing your users to learn how to properly write JSON.